# bundle install error for elasticbeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just added this new Gem to my Gemfile: `gem 'pg_query'` and when I run `bundle install` locally, everything works just fine. However, when I try to deploy to elasticbean stalk, I get this error that I wasn't getting before:

```
2021/11/18 00:33:20.171799 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [stage ruby application]. Stop running the command. Error: install dependencies in Gemfile failed with error Command /bin/sh -c bundle install failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Your lockfile was created by an old Bundler that left some things out.
You can fix this by adding the missing gems to your Gemfile, running bundle install, and then removing the gems from your Gemfile.
The missing gems are:
* google-protobuf depended upon by pg_query
```

Here's my `Gemfile.lock`: https://pastebin.com/X9VqfFkK

Here's my `Gemfile`: https://pastebin.com/e9aBu9EQ

Any ideas what might be going on? I feel like this is related to elastic beanstalk since I've had trouble with installing gems on there in the past.

Comment: If you're trying to move past this issue, it seems like updating Bundler and/or adding that dependency would be the next steps.

Comment: Hey @JakeWorth, I'm not sure what exactly I should update and to what version in this case, and if you check the `Gemfile.lock`, the dependency already exists there, so not sure how to proceed past this error to get deploys working again.

Comment: Try `gem install bundler` and make sure you're on the latest (v2.2.31 as of this writing, although I don't totally understand how Bundler's versioning works). Then run `bundle install` and make sure that version is at the bottom of the lockfile. If that doesn't work, try removing the lockfile and regenerating it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the requested gem google-protobuf is only included for macOS/Darwin operating systems. To have it included in Gemfile.lock for Linux systems, you'll need to run the following command locally:

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

(I'm presuming Elastic Beanstalk uses Linux - adjust the platform as needed)

My understanding is this applies for gems that have versions compiled for particular platforms. Bundler doesn't include *all* known platforms by default - so if your development and deployment environments are different, then adding the appropriate platforms ensures further bundling covers all relevant situations.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have changed anything within `Gemfile.lock`, should there be something added/changed? This was the entire output:

`[11/18/21 3:06:42] ➜  git:(develop) bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
Writing lockfile to Gemfile.lock`

Comment: Hmm, yes there should be something changed in Gemfile.lock. Perhaps updating to a newer version of Bundler would help? But glad you found a solution - just be warned that later updates to Gemfile.lock by bundler could reverse your manual changes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future who may run into this, thanks to @pat for pointing this out, it looks like the solution was to manually change this line in my `Gemfile.lock` from:

```
google-protobuf (3.19.1-x86_64-darwin)
```

to:

```
google-protobuf (3.19.1)
```

After that, the deploy worked and `bundle install` also worked locally! The platform on my elastic beanstalk is running Linux, so I think that was one of the reasons for the initial error.